# How to define a type that represents a Unit type in Haskell?

Tags: scala, haskell

Suppose I have a function `fail'`

```
fail' :: ()
fail' = error "Ka-boom!"
```

I want to define a function `failOrNum` which is a lazy function.

```
failOrNum :: () a => (a -> a) -> Num -> Num
failOrNum f n = n + 1
```

Example:

```
failOrNum fail' 5
```

What type of `failOrNum` function should I specify to satisfy the conditions?

I want to achieve something similar to Scala approach:

```
object LazyComputation extends App {
  def failOrInt(execution: => Unit, n: Int): Int = n + 1

  println {
    failOrInt({throw new RuntimeException("Ka-boom!")}, 5)
  }
}
```

Comment: Uhm... won't that Scala code always ignore the `execution` argument? Can you make an example where that is relevant? I don't understand what you are really trying to achieve here.

Comment: Is it that you want to define an Int that will only crash the program when you use that Int?  That will happen automatically if you define `x::Int; x=error "crash"`.

Comment: @jamshidh I want to define a type of function `f` in type declaration of function `failOrNum` instead of writing `(a -> a)`.

Comment: Well, `fail'` is actually `forall a. a` (or just `:: a`). It's not really clear what you actually want to do. After all, if `failOrInt` does not use the first argument at all, the type is arbitrary, and it's `failOrInt :: Num b => a -> b -> b`.

Comment: @Zeta Yeap, that's what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Why does your function `fail'` even exist? How is that a useful function to have?

Comment: @immibis It's just a wrapper around `error` with a hard-coded message.

Comment: @chepner Why would you want a pure function to crash when it's not actually being evaluated?

Comment: Also, what does "a type that represents a Unit type" even mean?

Comment: @immibis Not sure what you mean. `failOrNum fail' 5` *doesn't* fail; it returns 6.

Comment: @chepner The asker seems to want `failOrNum fail' 5` to fail. I'm asking why you'd want it to fail.

Comment: They're asking for a lazy function, and since `f` isn't used in the body of the function, I assume that means `f` never gets evaluated (and thus does *not* fail).

Answer (score 4):

It's not 100% clear to me what you want to do. But one way to fix your syntax and type errors would be like this:

```hs
fail' :: () -> ()
fail' _ = error "kaboom"
-- OR, to cause errors before this is even applied to an argument,
-- fail' = error "kaboom"
-- these two are distinguishable *only* by the seq function

failOrNum :: Num a => (() -> ()) -> a -> a
failOrNum _ n = n+1
```

However, I find this a very odd thing to want: there are really only a few semantically distinct inhabitants of `() -> ()`, and most of them are not really usefully distinguishable from within the pure side of Haskell. You would probably be better suited by a type with more easily distinguishable inhabitants.